# I commit a essay to the github, but my blogger doesn't show it

Tags: jekyll

Just a month ago, I could use the following commands to post a essay:

```
rake post title="test"
git add .
git commit -m"test"
git push origin master
```

However, now the commands don't work even though I've committed to Github!

The figure is as follows:
[image: on the github]
[image: doesn't show on blogger]

Answer (score 1):

I've found the reason. It is because that I've commit several essays in one time and there's something wrong with some one, then the others can't display in a right way though they are committed to the github.
I think maybe the page funciton has throws exception, whatever, I'll check out what kind of error I've made in my essay.

Comment: I find the reason, that the essay categories doesn't accept "+"